# Stopped on initramfs prompt after reinstalling "initramfs-tools-core"

Tags: boot, 16.04, apt, mount, initramfs

Executed the command *sudo apt-get install --reinstall initramfs-tools-core* after facing some dependency issues on installing a package using apt-get. Then laptop got stuck on initramfs.[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yDTRk.png)

Comment: What made you think that initramfs-tools-core had anything to do with dependency issues in apt-get? At the initramfs prompt, type "exit" and you should get to a # prompt. Type `ls -al /boot`. Edit that into your question.

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar issue:

1. Boot into recovery mode.
   Restart the computer and when the screen light comes on, press and hold the **shift key**. Select  **advance option**, then **select recovery mode.**
2. The displayed content on the screen will tell you the disk that needs manual fsck.

   For example, you'll see **/dev/sdaX needs manual fcsk**
3. Run fsck **/dev/sdaX**

   **X** in sdaX is the disk number (See an example below).

   fsck /dev/sda5
4. Run **reboot -f** to reboot

You should be good to go.